# Continuous order preserving function

Tags: general-topology, lattice-orders

Give an example of continuous function which is order preserving and its inverse is not order preserving ?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @Apurv f:R to R ,f(x)=-x is continuous but not order preserving ....but its inverse is itself???? still didn't get a hint

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is an order-preserving function on a totally-ordered set, and $f$ has an inverse, then $f^{-1}$ must be order-preserving.  Perhaps you're dealing with a partially ordered set.  Then you could have cases where $x$ and $y$ are incomparable, but $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are comparable.

Comment: I think about  function from Natural numbers to integers say f(x)=x+1 , now if x<y in (N natural) then f(x)<(fy) in (Z integers ) but if we take tow negative integers less than -1 there inverse image will be not comparable in N but we can claim this assumption since f is not bijective realy confused @Robert Isreal

Comment: The natural numbers and the integers are both totally ordered.  Your example is a function that does not have an inverse.  Ordinarily when one says "its inverse" in English, that would imply that you're assuming the inverse exists.  But maybe that's not the case here, especially if this question is translated from some other language.

Comment: sorry about my level in English ...yes I should think about bijection continuous order preserving function but there inverse"will be exist for sure"but is not order preserving

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution let X be finite has more than one point  set define a bijective function f:X to X where X as domain has discrete topology and X as co-domain has indiscrete topology
Now f it is clear continuous hence its order preserving(by Lemma2.2 J.P. MAY page 3) but its
       inverse is not continuous and hence its not order preserving ....:)

Comment: What order does it not preserve?

Comment: continuous functions between finite spaces are order preserving

Comment: the order is x < y iff x belong to minimal basic open set of y